# Compact Clojure code for regular expression matches and their position in string

Tags: regex, clojure

Stuart Halloway gives the example

```
(re-seq #"\w+" "The quick brown fox")
```

as the natural method for finding matches of regex matches in Clojure. In his book this construction is contrasted with iteration over a matcher. If all one cared about were a list of matches this would be great. However, what if I wanted matches and their position within the string? Is there a better way of doing this that allows me to leverage the existing functionality in java.util.regex with resorting to something like a sequence comprehension over each index in the original string? In other words, one would like to type something like

> (re-seq-map #"[0-9]+" "3a1b2c1d")

which would return a map with keys as the position and values as the matches, e.g.

```
{0 "3", 2 "1", 4 "2", 6 "1"}
```

Is there some implementation of this in an extant library already or shall I write it (shouldn't be too may lines of code)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can fetch the data you want out of a `java.util.regex.Matcher` object.

```
user> (defn re-pos [re s]
        (loop [m (re-matcher re s)
               res {}]
          (if (.find m)
            (recur m (assoc res (.start m) (.group m)))
            res)))
#'user/re-pos
user> (re-pos #"\w+" "The quick brown fox")
{16 "fox", 10 "brown", 4 "quick", 0 "The"}
user> (re-pos #"[0-9]+" "3a1b2c1d")
{6 "1", 4 "2", 2 "1", 0 "3"}
```

Comment: Thanks Brian. Maybe re-pos should find its way into the regex library.

Comment: I have a little problem with this. (re-pos #"ATAT" "GATATATGCATATACTT") should return {9 "ATAT", 3 "ATAT", 1 "ATAT"} but it returns {9 "ATAT", 1 "ATAT"}.

Comment: If you want to count overlapping matches, change the regex a little: (re-pos #"(?=(ATAT))" "GATATATGCATATACTT") returns {9 "", 3 "", 1 ""}.  If you want to get back the matched text, you need to do (.group m 1) instead of (.group m).

Comment: Could someone please explain what #"(?=(ATAT))"  means? What does the ?= mean?

Answer (score 2):

You can apply any function to the java.util.regex.Matcher object and return its results (simmilar to Brian's solution, but without explicit `loop`):

```
user=> (defn re-fun
         [re s fun]
         (let [matcher (re-matcher re s)]
           (take-while some? (repeatedly #(if (.find matcher) (fun matcher) nil)))))
#'user/re-fun

user=> (defn fun1 [m] (vector (.start m) (.end m)))
#'user/fun1

user=> (re-fun #"[0-9]+" "3a1b2c1d" fun1)
([0 1] [2 3] [4 5] [6 7])

user=> (defn re-seq-map
         [re s]
         (into {} (re-fun re s #(vector (.start %) (.group %)))))

user=> (re-seq-map #"[0-9]+" "3a1b2c1d")
{0 "3", 2 "1", 4 "2", 6 "1"}
```