# How can I get the positions of regex matches in ClojureScript?

Tags: regex, clojure, clojurescript

In Clojure I could use something like this solution: [Compact Clojure code for regular expression matches and their position in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262195/compact-clojure-code-for-regular-expression-matches-and-their-position-in-string), i.e., creating a `re-matcher` and extracted the information from that, but re-matcher doesn't appear to be implemented in ClojureScript. What would be a good way to accomplish the same thing in ClojureScript?

**Edit:**

I ended up writing a supplementary function in order to preserve the modifiers of the regex as it is absorbed into `re-pos`:

```
(defn regex-modifiers
  "Returns the modifiers of a regex, concatenated as a string."
  [re]
  (str (if (.-multiline re) "m")
       (if (.-ignoreCase re) "i")))

(defn re-pos
  "Returns a vector of vectors, each subvector containing in order:
   the position of the match, the matched string, and any groups
   extracted from the match."
  [re s]
  (let [re (js/RegExp. (.-source re) (str "g" (regex-modifiers re)))]
    (loop [res []]
      (if-let [m (.exec re s)]
        (recur (conj res (vec (cons (.-index m) m))))
        res))))
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) method of JS `RegExp` object. The returned match object contains an `index` property that corresponds to the index of the match in the string.

Currently clojurescript doesn't support constructing regex literals with the `g` mode flag (see [CLJS-150](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-150)), so you need to use the `RegExp` constructor. Here is a clojurescript implementation of the `re-pos` function from the linked page:

```
(defn re-pos [re s]
  (let [re (js/RegExp. (.-source re) "g")]
    (loop [res {}]
      (if-let [m (.exec re s)]
        (recur (assoc res (.-index m) (first m)))
        res))))

cljs.user> (re-pos "\\w+" "The quick brown fox")
{0 "The", 4 "quick", 10 "brown", 16 "fox"}
cljs.user> (re-pos "[0-9]+" "3a1b2c1d")
{0 "3", 2 "1", 4 "2", 6 "1"}
```

Comment: Thanks! That is excellent! The only gotcha with this solution is that it requires a string rather than a regex literal, making it incongruent with re-seq & co. Do you know if there's any reliable way of converting a regex literal to a string for use in this function?

Comment: The `source` property of regexp objects returns the text source. I updated the answer so that `re-pos` takes a regular expression object instead of a string.

Comment: You bring much honor to your ancestors.

Comment: A word of caution, this will infinite loop: `(re-pos #"" "anything")`