# Index of a substring in ClojureScript

Tags: string, clojurescript

There doesn't seem to be a built-in CLJS method to check for the index of a substring (e.g. the index of "scr" in "clojurescript" is 7).  This can be done with regexes as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18735665/how-can-i-get-the-positions-of-regex-matches-in-clojurescript), but that's quite verbose and is a little bit overkill for common use.  Is there any way to quickly and easily check for the existence of a character or substring within a string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because ClojureScript has access to all native JavaScript, we can use built-in JS functions like [.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).  This makes it fairly simple to do things like:

```
> (.indexOf "clojurescript" "scr")
  7
```

As Joaquin noted, this also makes it very simple to determine the existence of a substring as well:

```
> (not= -1 (.indexOf "clojurescript" "scr"))
  true
> (not= -1 (.indexOf "clojurescript" "asd"))
  false
```

Comment: I would suggest you update the answer for the question:

> Is there any way to quickly and easily check for the existence of a character or substring within a string?

`(= -1 (.indexOf "clojurescript" "asd"))`

Comment: Good suggestion!  That's actually what I was using it for in my code - I don't know how I forgot!